# Python nested dictionary on __setitem__ only. __getitem__ raises KeyError if item is not found

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a flexible nested dictionary that will raise a key error if a user tries to access a key that doesn't exist.

For a fully nested dict I've used this in the past:

`nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict)`

But I don't like that when I try to access a key that doesn't exist nested_dict returns a defaultdict. I would like to be able to add key value pairs even if the key doesn't exist, but I would like it to raise a KeyError if I try to directly access a key that doesn't exist.

I've tried things like this:

```
class NestedDict(dict):

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if type(self[item]) == NestedDict:
            raise KeyError
        return self[item]
```

But can't figure out how to break the recursion. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of `defaultdict` is exactly avoiding raising keyerrors - so it is not the best candidate for raising KeyErrors.

Instead, you can inherit from `collections.UserDict` (instead of dict)  which will take care of a lot of corner cases for you, and focus on writing `__setitem__`, `__getitem__` and `__delitem__` to have the behavior you want.

Then, comes the non-trivial part:

when doing `mydict["a"]["b"]["c"] = 1`, Python will first retrieve `mydict["a"]` through `__getitem__`. Then perform another `__getitem__` call on the value returned, to get the key `"b"`, and only then call `__setitem__`, on the object returned. Your `__getitem__` can't "know" before hand if a retrieved key will be subsequently used as a dictionary and `__setitem__` will be called on it, or if the user will simply use the retrieved value for any other end.

This is not resolvable at all. You could think of workarounds, like a "timeout" after which, if `__setitem__` is not called, an error will be raised. Or a proxy object which will raise a KeyError is *any* *other* *action* than `__setitem__` is attempted on the object.  (The later is actually feasible)

But instead, I'd suggest you consider picking a joining character for your nested keys - so you can split the keys in `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods, and handle everything. So, instead of trying:
`mydict["a"]["b"]["c"] = 1`, you could do `mydict["a.b.c"]`. This way, Python will call `__setitem__` directly on the root dictionary, which can split the key, and call `__setitem__` as required on nested values.
F-strings can be used to form the keys, when the intermediate parts are in variables, for example:  `mydict[f"{rootkey}.{midlekey}.pet_name"]`

```
from collections import UserDict
from collections.abc import Mapping

class NestedDict(UserDict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if not isinstance(key, tuple):
            key = tuple(key.split("."))
        element = self.data[key[0]]
        if len(key) == 1:
            return element
        return element[key[1:]]
    
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if not isinstance(key, tuple):
            key = tuple(key.split("."))
        if len(key) == 1
            if isinstance(value, Mapping) and not isinstance(value, NestedDict):
                 value  = NestedDict(value)
            self.data[key[0]] = value
            return
        element = self.data.setdefault(key[0], NestedDict())
        element[key[1:]] = value
    
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if not isinstance(key, tuple):
            key = tuple(key.split("."))
        if len(key) == 1:
            del self.data[key[0]]
        else:
            del self[key[0]][key[1:]]
```

This, although simple, will work surprisingly well .

If you need a similar approach which can handle any JSON valid structure (mixing dicts and lists),  it can become a lot more complex with all corner cases -  I am the author of a package which handles that in a nice way. If you need the functionality, install "extradict" with pip and use `extradict.NestedData` instead.

And as Pranav Hosangadi very assertively commented:

"Note that this class also works with tuple keys, so you could do mydict["a", "b", "c"] to get the same result. IMO using tuples instead of a joined string is better because it doesn't prevent your keys from containing the split character"

Yes - sorry for not having written that before.

Comment: This will do the trick for me, thank you so much!

Comment: Note that this class also works with tuple keys, so you could do `mydict["a", "b", "c"]` to get the same result. IMO using tuples instead of a joined string is better because it doesn't prevent your keys from containing the split character.

Comment: Thanks - I've added that to the answer - as it is missing.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for isn't possible. The first part of executing `d[a][b] = c` is reading `d[a]`. If you want to forbid reading `d[a]` when that key isn't present, then you can't write to `d[a][b]` when `d[a]` isn't present.